# Three.js MeshBasicMaterial Color isn't showing up correctly

Tags: react-native, three.js

I have a three.js `scene` where the `lighting` and `renderer` are defined as:

```
const ambientLight = new AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const directionalLight = new DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
directionalLight.position.set(0, 6, 0);
scene.add(directionalLight);

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvasRef.current! });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xeeeeee);
```

and I am creating some `Mesh` objects where I set the material to a `MeshBasicMaterial` like so, where the materialColor is an object with keys r,g,b,a:

```
const newMaterial = new MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: new Color(
      materialColor.r,
      materialColor.g,
      materialColor.b
    ),
    opacity: materialColor.a / 255,
    side: DoubleSide,
  });
```

The rgba value, if I `console.log` it, is for example `rgba(255,0,0,255)`
As far as I know, if I create a material this way with `(255,0,0,255)`, then it should appear pure `Red`.

It is appearing bright White.
What am I missing here?

I tried various Color() definitions like asRGB(), or dividing or multiplying the rgba input by 255, I also tried enabling shadows and so on but nothing changed the output.

If I hardcode a color into the MeshBasicMaterial, so instead of using:

```
color: new Color(
      materialColor.r / 255,
      materialColor.g / 255,
      materialColor.b / 255
    ),
    opacity: materialColor.a / 255,
```

I use:

```
color: new Color(
      255,
      0,
      0
    ),
    opacity: 1.0,
```

then the Mesh is red.
I am expecting the rgba color to be reflected in the color of the Mesh in the scene according to my rgba input.

Comment: Inputs to the THREE.Color constructor are on the 0–1 scale, not 0–255. Opacity is similarly 0–1. Writing `new Color( 1, 0, 0 )` will create a red color. MeshBasicMaterial is not affected by lights, so that part of the code is not required.